# how to set correct scheduler time

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, quartz-scheduler, ejb-3.1

I can invoke EJB Scheduler using XML (Or I can do with @Schedule annotation). For instance something like this: [ejb-jar.xml]

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
        <enterprise-beans>
            <session>
                <ejb-name>[name]</ejb-name>
                <ejb-class>[path]</ejb-class>
                <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
                <timer>
                    <schedule>
                        <minute>*/30</minute>
                        <hour>*</hour>
                        <month>*</month>
                        <year>*</year>
                    </schedule>
                    <timeout-method>
                        <method-name>[method name]</method-name>
                    </timeout-method>
                </timer>
            </session>
        </enterprise-beans>
    </ejb-jar>
```

If I need to run this Scheduler every day at mid night should I write something like this?

```
  <schedule>
      <minute>*</minute>
      <hour>0</hour>
      <month>*</month>
      <year>*</year>
  </schedule>
```

and If I need to 01:00 AM, will this be correct?

```
  <schedule>
      <minute>*</minute>
      <hour>1</hour>
      <month>*</month>
      <year>*</year>
  </schedule>
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For every day at midnight would be something like:

```
<schedule>
  <minute>0</minute>
  <hour>0</hour>
</schedule>
```

Every day at 1:00 AM:

```
<schedule>
  <minute>0</minute>
  <hour>1</hour>
</schedule>
```

Keep in mind that `*` is a wildcard meaning *all possible values for a given attribute*, I omitted month and year since their default value is `*` and you could actually omit the minute cause its default value is `0`.

For every minute of every day:

```
<schedule>
  <minute>*</minute>
  <hour>*</hour>
</schedule>
```

For every 10 seconds of every minute of every day:

```
<schedule>
  <second>*/10</second>
  <minute>*</minute>
  <hour>*</hour>
</schedule>
```

`x/y` means every `y` starting from `x`, and `*/y` means every `y` starting from `0`.

From your examples, something like these:

```
<schedule>
  <minute>*</minute>
  <hour>0</hour>
  <month>*</month>
  <year>*</year>
</schedule>
```

means every day for every minute between 12:00 AM to 12:59 AM, i.e. 12:00, 12:01, 12:02...

For more info, [check this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

Comment: thanks. And I have another additional question:

if I need to write every minute I will just write  <minute>1</minute> does not it? 

and If I need every 10 second? <second> */6</second> ? is it correct?

Comment: can u give me this examples, too? thanks :) And I will check it as an answered :)

Comment: and <minute>5</minute> <hour>0</hour> - this means every day for every 30 minute between 12:00 AM to 12:30 AM, i.e. 01:00, 01:30... is it right?

Comment: nope, <minute>5</minute> <hour>0</hour> means every day at 12:05 AM, just edited the post, and check the link, i's all explained there too

Comment: OK, OK unrestand.  <minute>*/12</minute> <hour>0</hour> means every 5 minute. does not it?

Comment: sorry ,  <minute>*/12</minute>  means, every 12 minute of hours :)) thanks :)

Comment: nope, <minute>*/12</minute> <hour>0</hour> means at (12:00,12:12,12:24,12:36,12:48), the forward slash doesn't mean divided by, it's simply for `x/y`: every `y` starting from `x` and if `x` is `*` starting from `0`, in this case every 12 minutes starting from 0